# Could it possible to change the name of folder after creating django project?

Tags: python, django

[The result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3eFZ.png)
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYZEZ.png)

When I try to change the default folder name which is same as the django project, here comes warning from pycharm:

1. WSGI_APPLICATION='backend_ch1_sec1.wsgi.application' in the setting.py

   After changing 'backend_ch1_sec1.wsgi.application' to 'backend.wsgi.application' pycharm warns:
2. Django settings for backend_ch1_sec1 project

How the could it work in the picture one?

Answer (score 0):

In settings:
You need to change `ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'`

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'
```

then it will run.

Comment: thanks, mate that works! Use tools replace all "backend_ch1_sec1"

Answer (score 0):

If you used good IDE you can refactor the folder name... and some change like this....

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'your_project_name.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'your_project_name.wsgi.application'
```